# Get first few results after preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am doing a simple web scraping for images.

```
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

$images return

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
   [length] => 19
)
```

If I print $src inside foreach loop, it shows 19 results.From those 19 results if i again print $src after http matching it shows 11 results. But I want first 5 result from those 11 results after preg_match.

How is it possible?

```
foreach ($images as $keys=>$image) {                

   $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    if(preg_match('/^http/', $src)){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test with the below code

```
$loopCount = 1;
foreach ($images as $keys=>$image) {                
   $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    if(preg_match('/^http/', $src)) {
        //assuming here you need to check count
        $loopCount ++;
        //your action
        if($loopCount > 5) {
           break;  //to avoid unnecessary loops
        }
    }
}
```

**It will give you the first 5 regex matching records**

Comment: Exact as i expect.

Comment: @SubhankarBhattacharjee, Please accept the answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass third parameter to `preg_match` function which returns all matched results

```
foreach ($images as $keys=>$image) {                

   $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    $matches = [];
    if(preg_match('/^http/', $src,$matches)){   // pass third parameter 
                                  ^^ will store all matched results

       print_r($matches); // Will show all matched results
       // Now you can use any of matched results for `$matches`

       // just an example
       $data[] = $matches[0];
       $data[] = $matches[1];
       $data[] = $matches[2];
       $data[] = $matches[3]; 
       $data[] = $matches[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to stop the loop if "first 5 results" are obtained:

```
$count = 5;
foreach ($images as $keys => $image) {

   if (!count) break;   // avoid redundant loop iterations
   $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
   if (preg_match('/^http/', $src)) {
       // processing the image item
       $count--;
   }
}
```